# Arabic Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have been learning some Arabic mostly for fun. I am looking for the Arabic Stack Exchange site but cannot find it. I am sure I saw it lying around a few months ago or so. Any idea what happened to it?

Comment: That's one way (which feels rather antagonistic of the community managers) of putting it... the site was not self-sustaining (meaning - not enough activity and not enough active users to keep the site going) and was therefor closed down.

Comment: I'd also support arabic.stackexchange.com. time for a new proposal.

Comment: Duolingo just launched its Arabic for English speakers course a week ago.  If there was anytime to reconsider revisiting the idea of an Arabic Stack Exchange, now might be it.  Anyone want to take this on again?

Comment: @Gewure, here is the link to a brand new proposal. Please follow and support: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123866/arabic-language?referrer=Yzc1MjllM2QwMjVkMGFhN2ZkNTljYzM4MGFhYjQ5ZDZlZmY4NWQ1ZDRhZTY1NWFjOGE1ZTZhNzVlNTc5OGIzNT_lCSOrW5jf30GiLzwp9ms6fpZke2NZMMUtT1-AZELs0

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It was [closed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62022/arabic-language) due to inactivity in private beta.

There was also [another Arabic Language proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/105382/arabic-language) which was subsequently deleted.

Comment: It's never too late to start a new proposal, the key for success is to **gather enough people in advance, before starting it**. :)

Comment: @Shadow9, here is the link to a brand new proposal. Please follow and support: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123866/arabic-language?referrer=Yzc1MjllM2QwMjVkMGFhN2ZkNTljYzM4MGFhYjQ5ZDZlZmY4NWQ1ZDRhZTY1NWFjOGE1ZTZhNzVlNTc5OGIzNT_lCSOrW5jf30GiLzwp9ms6fpZke2NZMMUtT1-AZELs0

Comment: @TaoufikMohdit pointless. Area 51 is dead.

Comment: @Shadow, I am trying to gather support. Hopefully this time it will work out

Comment: I'm with you @TaoufikMohdit

Comment: @TaoufikMohdit Was just about to go ahead and vote before I found it was also deleted. Annoying.